# Avoid multiple src files in my html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a website I'm working on in Visual Studio 2013 and I'm mainly using AngularJS 1.2.6. In my index.html I have a src line for each .js file which for 3 page is 6 lines, 1 js file for each controller and 1 js page for each view.

Is there a way I could consolidate all of these lines into 1 .js file and call that .js file in my index.html?

Comment: Use MVC.Net bundling & minification: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification. 

Otherwise you can run a grunt task to bundle and minify everything: http://love2dev.com/#!article/Using-GruntJS-to-Bundle-and-Minify-JavaScript-and-CSS

Comment: Or you can call 1 js file and have that js file load all the other js files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) to build a custom build script for your *.js* files. In your case, you may want to use [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) with [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch).

If you are not familiar with grunt, feel free to read the [tutorial](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started).